# How to convert jsp to html in Address bar?

Tags: jsp, weblogic

I have created dynamic web application using JSP and Weblogic server.

I have an `index.jsp` file which will include all the details from `loginpage.jsp`. If i ran that application it showing `localhost:7001/LoginPageAll/` in address bar, but I need `localhost:7001/LoginPageAll/loginpage.html` in Address bar.
Please help on me this.

Comment: What is the action on your login form? I guess it just goes to your web app's Welcome file. Which seems to be index.jsp.  From there you can redirect to loginpage.html. If you want loginpage.html to actually be a JSP, then use Prog Mania's solution to map the URL to a JSP.

Answer (score 0):

use a `<jsp-file>` mapping in your web.xml ,

it maps a servlet( every jsp in the end becomes a servelt , so your jsp is a servlet in the end ),

which you can map to a url pattern (the URL Pateern that you want ) like the following :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginPageJSP</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<!--mapping-->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginPageJSP</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginPageAll/</url-pattern>   
</servlet-mapping>
```

ref: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html